# Verse with name

Tags: names, aleph-bet-letters

Saw a post about this so it reminded me of my question- we say that you say a Torah verse at the end of shemoneh esrei that begins with the first letter of your name and ends in the last letter of your name…what exactly is your name though? When it says to use the last letter of your name, is that the last letter of your last name or of your first name? Also is it our Aliyah name that we base it off of?

TLDR: my name is יעקב. Do I use yud and bet for my pasuk, or since I’m יעקב בן שמואל do I use yud and lamed. Or since my last name in Hebrew ends with a tzaddik, do I used yud and tzaddik?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely use only the first and last letters of your *given name*, no father's name and no last name. In some siddurim you can see explicitly that they list pesukim for each given name; some have the name in the pasuk, but other pesukim just begin/end with the first and last letters of the name.

As for what to do if you have two names, there are different opinions. My father was taught to only say one pasuk for the first name, but, for example, the "Siddur Bais Aharon V'Yisrael," which includes the minhagim of the Stolin community, says to say two (or more) pesukim, one for each given name.

Comment: the quality of this answer would be vastly improved if you were to cite sources for each of your claims.